# Transfer Symfony2 site onto localhost from web server

Tags: php, symfony

exactly as the title states, I am looking to transfer a website, built in Symfony2, from a web server, onto my localhost.

I have not done this before, and I am not sure what the steps would be to achieve the desired result, which woul be to have the website run perfectly from my localhost.

I have installed a blank version of Symfony2 onto my localhost, but I am not sure where to go from here?

Sorry for the vague question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be mainly 3 steps :

1. **Download the entire Symfony2 site folder** into your localhost. That folder would be the one containing the "app", "src", "web", etc. folder.
2. **Export** the database from the live webserver, and **import** it in your localhost. That could be done using PhpMyAdmin...
3. Open the file "**parameters.ini**" located in "app/config", and change the database settings to match the one on your localhost.

That should probably do it. Please notice that there is no need to install a blank copy of Symfony2, since you'll get it anyway by downloading your whole application.

If something is still not working, you may want to have a look at .htaccess files located in the root folder, or in the "web" folder.