# How to move a Symfony project from web hosting to localhost?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I tried some solutions (ex: [Transfer Symfony2 site onto localhost from web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194325/transfer-symfony2-site-onto-localhost-from-web-server)), but never works, the result is always a blank page.

The project is on Symfony 2.3 and my php version is 5.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When accessing a Symfony2 site locally you need reference one of the routing files in the web folder directly. So try http://localhost/app_dev.php/ and it might give you an error message telling you what is going wrong. Also you can check the log files in the /app/logs folder to see what the problem might be.

**Edit:**
There are also several command line tools that might be needed to set up the project.

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

This will check the database is in sync with your code and update the database if necessary.

```
app/console assetic:dump
app/console assets:install
app/console cache:clear
```

These are used to install css, javascript and other static assets as well as clearing the cache.

Comment: When i try http://localhost/app_dev.php/ appears a blank page again. The logs files show only the doctrine debug.

The database is sync and I also install css, js and clear the cache

Comment: If that page is showing blank then it looks like a server setup issue. Check your Apache error and access logs to see if there is anything in there. If not check out http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html to make sure your Apache configuration is correct.

Comment: Also make sure your apache configuration is pointing to the "web" folder and not the root folder of the symfony project.