# Symfony Authentication: I cannot pass the Login Page of an existing symfony project on my local server

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I have difficulty in passing my login page of an already existing Symfony project. I have followed the process [laid down here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194325/transfer-symfony2-site-onto-localhost-from-web-server/34182976#34182976) but I still have issues in passing the login page, didn't even give me error or anything. It just keeps redirecting me to the same login page.

Also no error is written in the apps/log/dev.log file. I can see Sessions are created each time I tried to visit the site through the database phpMyAdmin on localhost.

This is my app/config/config.yml file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: easy.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: %kernel.debug%
    form:            true
    csrf_protection: true
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'], assets_version: v32 }
    default_locale:  %locale%
    trust_proxy_headers: false

twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
        applicationUrl: http://10.50.1.39:8080/Performance/web/app_dev.php
    form:
        resources:
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Form:label.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:JobPosition:business_unit_department_multiple.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:FunctionalRole:business_unit_department_single.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:FunctionalRole:app_functional_role_position.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:FunctionalRole:app_functional_role_position_fixed.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Employee:app_employee_job.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Skill:app_skill_applied.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:JobFunction:app_job_function.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Job:app_job_filter.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Job:app_job_all_filter.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Competency:app_competency_area.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Competency:app_competency_filter.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Form:datepicker.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:DepartmentObjective:app_goal.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:DepartmentObjective:app_goal_filter.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:DepartmentObjective:app_department_multiple.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:CompetencyObjective:app_competency_objective_type.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:CompetencyObjective:app_competency_objective.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Kpi:app_kpi_type.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:AppraisalForm:app_appraisal_form_filter.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:AppraisalCycle:app_appraisal_cycle_business_unit_department.html.twig
            - AppraisalAdminBundle:Form:app_attachment.html.twig

swiftmailer:
    encryption: tls
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       mail.ipnxnigeria.net
    username:   perfmgt@ipnxnigeria.net
    password:   ipnx
    spool:
        type: file
        path: "%kernel.root_dir%/spool"

doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        port:    "%database_port%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:    UTF8
```

This is my app/config/security.yml file

```html
security:
    encoders:
       Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
#        Appraisal\AdminBundle\Business\User\UserSession: sha512

    providers:
        AppSecurityBundleUserProvider:
            id: app_user_provider
#       default_provider:
#            memory:
#                users:
#                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        login:
            pattern:  ^/Admin/Login/ShowLogin
            security: false

        secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /Admin/Security/LoginCheck
                login_path: /Admin/Login/ShowLogin
                username_parameter: username
                password_parameter: password
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: /Admin/Default/
            logout:
                path:   /Admin/Security/Logout
                target: /Admin/Login/ShowLogin

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/Admin/Profile/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_APPRAISER, ROLE_APPRAISEE] }
        - { path: ^/Admin/Default/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_APPRAISER, ROLE_APPRAISEE] }
        #- { path: ^/Admin/AppraiserObjectiveSetting/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_APPRAISER] }
        #- { path: ^/Admin/Appraisee/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_APPRAISER] }
        - { path: ^/Admin/, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN] }
```

This is my LoginController.php file

```html
<?php

namespace Appraisal\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

use Appraisal\AdminBundle\Business;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;

/**
 *@Route("/Login")
 */
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/ShowLogin/",  name="Appraisal_Login_ShowLogin")
     */
    public function ShowLoginAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $formErrors = array();
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $formError = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $formError = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }        

        $data = array(
            'form_url' => $this->generateUrl('Security_LoginCheck'),
            'form_error' => $formError
        );
        return $this->render('AppraisalAdminBundle:Login:LoginPage.html.twig', $data);
    }
}
```

This is my Login.html.twig view

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title | default('Appraisal System')}}</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    {% block header %}
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/jquery-easyui/themes/default/easyui.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/jquery-easyui/themes/icon.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/style.css') }}">
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/jquery-easyui/jquery-1.8.0.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/jquery-easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/general.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function switchPage(pageTitle, pageHref) {
            var centerPanel = jQuery('#main').layout('panel', 'center');
            centerPanel.panel('setTitle', pageTitle);
            centerPanel.panel('refresh', pageHref);
        }
    </script>

    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topBanner">
        {% block topBanner %}
            <img src="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/images/company-logo.jpg')}}" height="58px" />
        {% endblock %}        
    </div>
    <div class="easyui-layout" id="main" style="height:550px;margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">  
        <div id="content" region="center">
            <div id="LoginDialog" class="easyui-dialog" title="Login" style="width:500px;height:200px"
                closable="false">  
                <form id="LoginForm" class="stdform" method="post" action="{{ form_url }}">
                    <p>
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <span class="field">
                            <input type="textbox" name="username" style="width: 180px"/>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <span class="field">
                            <input type="password" name="password" style="width: 180px"/>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label></label>
                        <span class="field">
                            <label for="selection" class="error" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 50%">
                                {% if form_error is not empty %}Login failed{% endif %}

                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                
                    <p class="stdformbutton" id="LoginForm_submit_button_p">
                        <a class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" href="javascript:submitForm('LoginForm')">
                            <span>Login</span>
                        </a>
                    </p>

                    <p class="stdformbutton" style="display: none" id="LoginForm_submit_ajax_loader">
                        <a class="ajax-loader"></a>
                    </p>
                </form>                                            
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;">
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 300px; margin-top: 10px">
            <b style="font-size: 11px">Powered by </b> <img src="{{ asset('bundles/designjeasyui/images/footer-logo.jpg')}}" height="20px" />    
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked the .htaccess file and the web root, have done the checking but I don't know what to do. I need to make some changes in the bundles but I cannot login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Victor. The problem is that i originally built the web app on windows platform(using wamp server) and i was trying to open it back on ubuntu (lamp server), which didn't work. I forgot that web apps built originally on windows may not work on any other OS platform but web apps built on Ubuntu (or linux-likes) can work on any other platform including windows. Let's note that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the link you provided  [Transfer Symfony2 site onto localhost from web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194325/transfer-symfony2-site-onto-localhost-from-web-server/34182976#34182976), step 2 says:

**2) Export the database from the live webserver, and import it in your localhost. That could be done using PhpMyAdmin...**

Have you checked if the database is correctly imported using PhpMyAdmin? (Or MySQL in terminal)

I have gotten this "can't get out of the login page" error already, and the times it happened to me it was because I forgot to run my Doctrine Fixtures. Forgetting to run my Fixtures resulted in not inserting my "standard" users into the Database, so I wasn't able to login.

Maybe you have a similar error :)

Verify your /app/config/parameters.yml and check if the database name, user and password are correct. They should be the database where your users are (see PhpMyAdmin or Or MySQL in terminal) and the user and password you use for PhpMyAdmin/MySQL

Comment: Thanks Victor. The problem is that i originally built the web app on windows platform(using wamp server) and i was trying to open it back on ubuntu (lamp server), which didn't work. I forgot that web apps built originally on windows may not work on any other OS platform but web apps built on Ubuntu (or linux-likes) can work on any other platform including windows. Let's note that.